# TableView javafx doesn't show the data

Tags: javafx, tableview, observable

first of this question in not exactly like what it is marked duplicate of. i'm trying to add data to a single column tableview but i can't figure for my life what am i missing. i only see an empty column. i have checked the naming convention, which you can see is ok.  if need anything else please ask. thanks

//Empolyee class

```
public class Employee {

    String name;

    Employee(String name){
         this.name = name;
    }
}
```

// Layout

```
private TableView<Employee> dataBase() {
    TableView<Employee> table = new TableView<>();

    TableColumn<Employee, String> name = new TableColumn<>("Name");
    name.setMinWidth(120);
    name.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));

    table.setItems(getEmployees());
    table.getColumns().add(name);

    return table;
}

private ObservableList<Employee> getEmployees() {

    ObservableList<Employee> data =FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    data.add(new Employee("DOE-1"));
    data.add(new Employee("DOE-2"));
    data.add(new Employee("DOE-3"));
    data.add(new Employee("DOE-4"));

    return data;
}


HBox body() {
    HBox body = new HBox();
    body.getChildren().addAll(dataBase());
    return body;
}

public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    mainPane.getChildren().addAll(body());
    primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: Also the class itself needs to be `public`.

Comment: naming convension is ok according to java, pls public isn't making any difference, i tried it.

Comment: it's the _exact_ duplicate (hint: your employee doesn't have a property called "name", neither in beans terms nor in fx terms)